# Why syntax error using case and array functions in postgreSQL ?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgreSQL database , can you explain me why i got syntax error ? I can't find any answer in documentation  [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html)

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validation(string_to_match varchar [], pattern 
    varchar , validation_type varchar) RETURNS boolean AS $$  
    DECLARE a_length ALIAS FOR $1;
    DECLARE result_validation ALIAS FOR $2;
    BEGIN

    CASE validation_type
      WHEN 'login' THEN array_length (string_to_match , 1) INTO $1 RAISE NOTICE 
    'Array length is %', $1; 
      WHEN 'register' THEN array_length(string_to_match,1) INTO $1 RAISE NOTICE 
    'Array length is %', $1;
      WHEN 'contact' THEN array_length(string_to_match,1) INTO $1 RAISE NOTICE 
    'Array length is %', $1;
    END CASE; 

    END;    
    $$ lANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> > ERROR:  syntax error at or near "array_length"
> >     LINE 7:    WHEN 'login' THEN array_length (string_to_match , 1) INTO...
> >                                  ^
> >     SQL state: 42601
> >     Character: 258

Comment: Try writing it as `when validation_type = 'login' ...when validation_type = 'register' ...etc` 
I'm not sure why but I've had this error before and that has worked as a work around.

Comment: `INTO $1 ` makes no sense at the place where you put it. What exactly do you expect that to do? You are also missing a `return` statement. You have to explain to us what that function is supposed to do. As far as I can tell, the CASE is completely unnecessary as you simply output the (same) array length in all cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this you want(?) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validation(string_to_match varchar [], pattern 
varchar , validation_type varchar) 
RETURNS boolean 
AS $$  
DECLARE a_length INT;
BEGIN

    IF validation_type =  'login' THEN
        a_length := array_length(string_to_match , 1); 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Array length is %', a_length; 
    ELSIF validation_type = 'register' THEN 
        a_length := array_length(string_to_match , 1); 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Array length is %', a_length; 
    ELSIF validation_type =  'contact' THEN 
        a_length := array_length(string_to_match , 1); 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Array length is %', a_length; 
    END IF; 

    RETURN true; -- or false ? 
END;    
$$ lANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks !! Yes but i didn't understood mine error ..
Can you explain me the logic behind array_length(string_to_match , 4); 
For example this function need to calculate length but i need to pass as parameter the array dimension and if not it will be error .. So what the logic behind length calculation if i have to pass the length in the beginning ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov -   You tried assigning variable value using `INTO`, but you missed `SELECT`, also you  tried to insert array length (which is int type) into array type; you have missed semi colons before `RAISE..`; also missed `return` from function

Comment: @Maks.Burkov - I'm not sure I understand your question about `array_length`. 4 here is not length you're passing in the beginning, it is dimension. so if you need calculate one dimensional array, second parameter always will be 1

Answer (score 0):

it's just a first intuiton but I think it's because of the space between array_length and (string_to_match, 1)

Comment: No, that's fine. This is not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

- `CASE WHEN THEN END` is not a statement, but an expression.
- Therefore it does not need those semicolons inside...
- And also `RAISE` cannot be used inside.
- What does **expression `INTO` variable** means?

Comment: It **is** an a statement in PL/pgSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.4.6

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto - Why RAISE cannot be used inside ?