# Can't understand why I got this "malformed array literal" error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can anybody explain to me what I am doing wrong ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validation(
   string_to_match varchar[],
   pattern varchar,
   validation_type varchar
) RETURNS boolean AS $$  
DECLARE a_length ALIAS FOR $1;
DECLARE result_validation ALIAS FOR $2;
BEGIN
    IF validation_type =  'login' THEN
        $1 := array_length(string_to_match,1); 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Login if , Array length is %', $1; 
    ELSIF validation_type = 'register' THEN 
        $1 := array_length(string_to_match,1); 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Array length is %', $1; 
    ELSIF validation_type =  'contact' THEN 
        $1 := array_length(string_to_match,1); 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Array length is %', $1; 
    END IF; 

    RETURN $1;
END;    
$$ lANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Invocation:

```
SELECT validation (
   '{1,2,3,4,5}',
    '([a-zA-Z]{2,20}[\.\-\_])([a-zA-Z]{2,20}[0-9]{2,20})@([a-z]{2,6})\.([a-z]{2,3})',
    'login');
```

The error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "5"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function validation(character varying[],character varying,character varying) line 7 at assignment
SQL state: 22P02
```

Comment: Again: rather than throwing some invalid code at you should explain what the function is supposed to to. Currently the `IF` is completely useless because you are always doing the same thing regardless which condition was true. And why didn't you use the correct code [from the answer you accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52871667)?

Answer (score 0):

`$1` is the first function parameter, so `$1`, `string_to_match` and `a_length` point to the same object of type `character varying[]`.

So the assignment

```
$1 := array_length(string_to_match,1);
```

tries to assign `5` to an array variable, which causes the error you observe.

It seems like you are confused about the role of `$1`. Omit  the `ALIAS FOR $1` part and use `a_length` instead of `$1`.